# TypeError: 'GetAggregatedReport' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm executing one python script and im getting the below error while inserting the data to PostgreSQL database.Below is the database schema and sample query i use.

Any suggestions on how to deal with it ?

```
cur.execute(cmd, api_response)
TypeError: 'GetAggregatedReport' object does not support indexing
```

Also i would like to add the datetime to the this table, If i have a timestamp in the table schema, How can i insert the current time to the table and what change i need to do?

Below is the sample script.

```
import psycopg2

def db_connect():
 try:
     DSN = "dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='postgres' port='5432'"
     conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)
     return conn
 except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
     print('database connection failed')
     quit()

start_dt = date(2020, 10, 1)
end_dt =  datetime.date(datetime.now())

connection=db_connect()

cur = connection.cursor()

cmd="""INSERT into email_stats(raw_data) SELECT %s"""

for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
  start_date = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  end_date = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

  try:
     api_response = api_instance.get_aggregated_smtp_report(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
     #print(api_response)
     cur.execute(cmd, api_response)
   
connection.commit()
```

Table schema

```
CREATE TABLE  email_stats
(raw_data text COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
WITH (OIDS = FALSE)TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Sample API response

```
Database connected...
Cursor initiated
Connection succesful
{'blocked': 0,
 'clicks': 0,
 'delivered': 140,
 'hard_bounces': 0,
 'invalid': 0,
 'opens': 7501,
 'range': '2020-10-29|2020-10-29',
 'requests': 4,
 'soft_bounces': 0,
 'spam_reports': 1,
 'unique_clicks': 0,
 'unique_opens': 3502,
 'unsubscribed': 9}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user123/Documents/sb.py", line 52, in <module>
    cur.execute(cmd, api_response)
TypeError: 'GetAggregatedReport' object does not support indexing
>>>
```

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what is in `api_response`.  You should also take a look at [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) in the psycopg2 docs. I'm going to guess that `api_response` is not in proper form to be a parameter, hence the 'object does not support indexing'.

Comment: @AdrianKlaverThanks a lot for the response, This error is making it difficult for me, tried various methods but could not able to get this inserted into database.I have updated the response data that i get from the api response, if you can let me know on this how to resolve it, will be ver helpful.

Comment: That is the print(__repr__) of the response. Try `print(type(ap_response))`, to see what you are actually dealing with. Whatever it is, is not capable of being used by `SELECT`. You could try `INSERT into email_stats(raw_data)  VALUES (%s)  cur.execute(cmd, str(api_response))`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver That i have tried already but was getting ,  cur.execute(cmd,str(api_response))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: The bottom line is you still have not indicated what `type(api_response)` is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem

Psycopg2 is iterating through `api_response`, which is not an iterable type. Psycopg2 is throwing an error because it expects an iterable type, from which it extract SQL variables.

## Solution

Replace:

```
cur.execute(cmd, api_response)
```

With:

```
cur.execute(cmd, (api_response,))
```

## References

Passing parameters to psycopg2: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#query-parameters

Comment: Thanks for the response, Tried that but was getting another exception          
 cur.execute(cmd,(api_response,))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'GetAggregatedReport'

Comment: @Sandeep you need to pass in text not the object. Psycopg2 is erroring since it’s getting an object that it can’t parse GetAggregateReport type into text. Hint: Consider implementing text conversion in __str__ method of GetAggregateReport if it doesn’t exist already. If it does exist use: wrap the api_response in str() call.